# Is passing different types of objects through an ObjectInputStream a good use case for instanceof?

Tags: java

I'm new to java and programming and I've been learning over the last few days or so.

I've read about how using the instanceof operator is bad practice, and I kind of understand why in their examples. However, I'm trying to write a client-server communication program and I'm trying to figure how to make a versatile platform for communication between them. So I made a messenger class and subclasses that extend it that hold different data types for communication.

I'm trying to figure out how the server can tell which of these subclasses that I've created is sent with the ObjectInputStream without using the instanceof operator to tell. Is using instanceof okay in this situation, or should the object sent through the ObjectInputStream always be known so that it can be casted? Am I on the right track, or does the structure of my program need rethinking?

Comment: The question as stated is a little too vague to answer well. Describe your design and goals and post some code showing how the communication between your programs is handled.

Comment: I haven't written much code yet; at this point I'm just trying to wrap my head around good practices in object-oriented programming so I can write something that isn't inefficient.

Comment: What I'm thinking right now is something like: the client enters a command which is put into an a string in the instance of the command subclass of the messenger object, and the server receives this command and get the data from the database or whatever. Then, depending on the command, the server could send a string, a json, an int, etc. and the client would receive it and go from there.

Comment: @TannerKrewson worrying about design patterns all day long is a big problem in java, and it often leads to overly complicated code. if you're just beginning to learn: mess around with the things you know, keep it goal oriented. then pick up a book on theory that you are developing an interest for (algorithms, design patterns, maths, domain specific topics, whatever is is you're into at the moment). do that for some time, then go back to messing around. rinse, repeat, and you'll become a good programmer :)

Comment: As I'm writing that I feel maybe I'm more confused about how I should be utilizing the ObjectInputStream/ObjectOutputStream or sockets in general. Should I have one ObjectInputStream that recieves all of the different types of data or should I have multiple that recieve objects that are assumed in a bunch of different methods.

Comment: @TannerKrewson you're worrying about something that is very hard to decide, even for programmers with a lot of experience. it's pretty much impossible to answer this without known _a lot_ about what exactly you want to achieve. my advice is stick with the object streams, it seems you've already tried them. just see how far you can get. don't forget: a programmer produces applications, not code! (unless you want to become a computer scientist, then its a different story :) )

Comment: I'd start with writing something simple to get your feet wet. I'd skip java serialization and ObjectInputStream altogether. Another consideration is whether your message objects actually need to be subclasses of each other - in a design in which they are not and simply carry their own type tags, the whole 'instanceof' thing goes away. When you're doing your own simple marshaling and unmarshaling from some format, say JSON, instanceof goes away as well since you're doing the instantiation and you know what you're supposed to be instantiating. Fancier JSON libraries such as GSON

Comment: can also do the mapping for you but, again, start very, very simple. A little bit of working code is a good way to focus on practical things and play with design on something that actually exists.

Answer (score 0):

It's fine, I'd say. There are some alternatives (like having a message interface with a `getType()` method and differentiating based on that) but they all have their caveats. Essentially you're dealing with unknown data at first, so some casting in one form or the other is unavoidable. The neat thing about your solution is that it's very easy to read, write *and* understand. Also not much can go wrong. So... go ahead!